# Redirect to a page if URL contains string

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, web

My business has been bought-out. As such we are re-branding and changing the URL's of our sites. I have 2 URL's pointing to one web server (the old, original URL and the new URL) and what I would like to do is have script on my pages to see if my user has visited the old URL. If they have I would then like them to be redirected to a particular html page to tell them that the site has changed and that they need to update their favourites. I do not want the redirect to be automated.

Basically any time the old URL is detected I would like them redirected to the redirect page to inform them

IF URL contains 'dls.myOLDwebsite.co.uk' THEN REDIRECT to: 'dls.mywebsite.co.uk/redirect.html'

The reason I would like to do this is because if the user is going to the new, correct address (example; dls.myNEWwebsite.co.uk) then I don't want any redirects or messages.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for this.

You need to add the following to the .htaccess file of your site

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} dls.myOLDwebsite.co.uk ^
RewriteRule ^/$ http://dls.mywebsite.co.uk/redirect.html [R=301,L]
```